# How do I request the name of an HTML button using python/flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

Here is the html code I have for my input button.

```
<input type="submit" name="{{ person.id }}" value="x" >
```

I'm not sure how to use flask/python to store the name of this button in a variable.

Also, I'm not sure if I'm even using the right attribute. Maybe I should be storing `person.id` in a different attribute.
(btw I want the value to be "x" because I want it to display that character so that it looks like a delete button)

This is the python/flask code that I tried.

```
button_value = request.form.get('x')
```

I knew that this was wrong, but I didn't know what else to do.

Comment: I feel you are confused. I f you need a button maybe the right way to go is using a real `<button></button>` or  `<a></a>` or even a `<input type="checkbox"></input>`. Could you clarify what are you trying to accomplish with this button you need?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input>` elements of with `type="submit"` are only supposed to be buttons that submit the form, not to hold data. If you need to pass `person.id` without creating a textbox, use the `hidden` attribute, like this:

```
<input name="x" value="{{ person.id }}" hidden>
```

Also, the `value` attribute is supposed to hold the value, not the name of the field (`person.id` in your example). Instead, you get `<input>`s by their `name` attribute. Because of this, the `name` attribute should be a constant, while the `value` attribute should change to whatever value is needed. To get the example input I used above, use this flask code:

```
input_value = request.form.get('x')
```

(Note: in real applications, use more descriptive `names`s, such as `"id"` or `"user_id"`)